# Should I use "certain" or "certainly" in the sentence below?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

We are encouraged to associate "certainly" sumptuous brands with a higher status.

Comment: We would not use the adverb _certainly_ to modify the noun _brands._ Have you learned the difference between an _adverb_ and an _adjective_ in English? We use _adverbs_ to modify _verbs,_ and _adjectives_ (like _certain_) to modify nouns.

Comment: Well, you _could_ use _certainly_, but it would modify _sumptuous_. Adverbs can also modify adjectives. However, I'm not sure that in this case that would make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, only adjectives modify nouns, and so "certain" is the correct choice to modify "brands".

However, you should also understand the difference in meaning.  Despite being in the same family, *certain* has an additional definition that *certainly* does not have:

> [**certainly**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/certainly) (adv):
>     1. used to reply completely or to emphasize something and show that there is no doubt about it.
>     2. very likely to happen.
>
> [**certain**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/certain) (adj):
>    1. having no doubt or knowing exactly that something is true, or known to be true, correct, exact, or effective,
>    2. impossible to avoid or extremely likely,
>    3. **particular but not named or described.**

In your example, you use the third meaning of *certain* to mean "a particular but unspecified set" of sumptuous brands.  Since *certainly* does not have this meaning, you would not use it.

Other examples:

> There are *certain* people who like to answer questions about English.
>
> *Certain* fair-skinned people should avoid direct sunlight, as they burn easily.
>
> Yes, she has a *certain* attractiveness, but she's still not a good actress.

Note the difference between the third example sentence and these two:

> Yes, she is *certainly* attractive, but she's still not a good actress.
>
> Yes, it is *certain* she is attractive, but she's still not a good actress.

Here *certain*/*certainly* have the other meaning, "without question".

Answer (score 1):

You should use "**certain**" if you are speaking about "**certain brands that are sumptuous**" since only an adjective can modify a noun.

You could use the adverb "**certainly**" to modify "**sumptuous**" but the phrase "**brands that are certainly sumptuous**" doesn't make sense.

Comment: What if it's modifying "sumptuous" and not "brands"?

Comment: @ColleenV it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can almost always write more than just the minimum one sentence answer, you just have to think of the other questions someone might have after they read it :)